# Java: Parse text markers as date

Tags: java, parsing, date

I'm looking for an existing library/class to do this kind of parsing

With a set of meta-values like:

- `now`
- `today`
- `yesterday`
- `X days ago`
- `X months ago`

It should provides me a `java.util.Date` object.
I know the implementation can be easy, but if it already exists is better

Thanks

Comment: If you're really lazy use [natty](http://natty.joestelmach.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Calendar class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

> The Calendar class is an abstract class that provides methods for
>   converting between a specific instant in time and a set of calendar
>   fields such as YEAR, MONTH, DAY_OF_MONTH, HOUR, and so on, and for
>   manipulating the calendar fields, such as getting the date of the next
>   week. An instant in time can be represented by a millisecond value
>   that is an offset from the Epoch, January 1, 1970 00:00:00.000 GMT
>   (Gregorian).

For example:

```
SimpleDateFormat fo = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
System.out.println(fo.format(cal.getTime()));
```

You can also have a look at the **[JODA TIME LIBRARY](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)**

Comment: If (for example) I have the value "today" how can I apply it to the Calendar object? My question is related to avoid a custom parser if it already exists. If not I'll make my own.

Comment: @DevilingMaster:- Posted an example to show how you can use the calendar class to get previous month.

Answer (score 1):

[Natty](http://natty.joestelmach.com/) seems a perfect fit for your need.

You can [try it out](http://natty.joestelmach.com/try.jsp) and it parsed all your examples perfectly.

Comment: Natty seems indeed a perfect match, I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

I think no library suitable with your expected but you can easily implement an Util with [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) or [DateUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html) of [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/)

Comment: If reimplementing from scratch, joda-time is great too.